# Multiple assignments in python

Tags: python

I need a clear explanation here.
Why does the following code work ?

```
foo1 = foo1[0] = [0]
```

Ok, I know assignments are done left to right.

How does python understand `foo1` is a list?

Btw I know `foo1` ends up as `[[...]]` its first element being itself.

Comment: Depends on what `foo1` was originally.  If looks like it was a list with at least one element in it.

Comment: Is the question purely theoretical, or you found any use to this kind of construct? @Makoto it does not depend on the previous use / definition of `foo1`.

Comment: @norok2:  Yeah it does.  You can't reference `foo1[0]` if `foo1` isn't indexable (e.g. like an object which doesn't have that property overridden or a number).

Comment: Theoretical question.

Comment: @Makoto Please copy paste OP's code into a fresh interpreter session.

Comment: Related: [Python Multiple Assignment Statements In One Line](//stackoverflow.com/q/32156515)

Comment: Also see [Simple Assignment Operator become Complicated in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/13657704) for more shenanigans with assignments.

Answer (score 29):

Because

```
foo1 = foo1[0] = [0]
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = [0]
foo1 = temp 
foo1[0] = temp
```

it first evaluates expression and then assigns from left to right. 
Analyzing this line by line you'll get what's going on:
- first a list is created in `temp`
- then list `temp` is assigned to `foo1` making it a list (answers your actual question)
- 3rd line just makes an assignment of first element to the list itself (thus [[...]] in output)

**Update 2:** changed related question as per @blhsing comment to a more related discussion: [Python Multiple Assignment Statements In One Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156515/python-multiple-assignment-statements-in-one-line)

Comment: Downvoted. While your explanation itself is correct, the doc quoted and your choice of a link to a "similar question" are completely wrong and unrelated to this question and your explanation. The citation you chose and the link you gave are in regards to an assignment of an expression list to a target list (as in `a, b = 1, 2`), whereas this question is about multiple assignments in a single statement (as in `a = b = 1`). See [Mark Dickinson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156515/python-multiple-assignment-statements-in-one-line) for the correct citation and reasoning.

Comment: @blhsing, agreed. updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Python variables know their types based on the type of variable assigned to it. It is a dynamically typed language. In your code, the interpreter sees `foo1 = foo1[0] = [0]` and it finds a value at the end, which is `[0]`. It is a list with one element `0`. Now, this gets assigned to the first element of the list `foo1` through `foo1[0] = [0]`. But since `foo1` is already declared, it creates an object which has a pointer to itself, and hence `foo1` gets self-referenced infinitely, with the innermost list having 0.

The structure of the list `foo1` will be the same when the code is `foo1 = foo1[0]`.

The object `foo1` has entered an infinite self-referenced loop.