# Tuple unpacking issue in reversing a linked list using tuple unpacking in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list, iterable-unpacking

Reversing Linked List [Leetcode-206](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/)

Initial Approach:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    prev= None
    while head:
        # print("-",prev,head)
        temp_nxt = head.next
        head.next = prev
        prev = head
        head = temp_nxt
        # print("=",prev,head)
    return prev
```

---

I encountered an unexpected issue when I tried to writing this code using tuple assignment/parallel assignment in Python.
Let's call this **Method-1**

```
prev, head, head.next = head, head.next, prev
```

I get an error, and the output is not as expected.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
                ^^^^^^^^^
    prev, head, head.next = head, head.next, prev
```

Output: [1,2,3]

```
- None ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}
= ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: None}} ListNode{val: 2, next: None}

- ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: None}} ListNode{val: 2, next: None}
```

However, when I use the following code, it works fine:
**Method-2**

```
prev, head.next, head = head, prev, head.next
```

Output: [1,2,3]

```
- None ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}}
= ListNode{val: 1, next: None} ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}

- ListNode{val: 1, next: None} ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}
= ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}} ListNode{val: 3, next: None}

- ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}} ListNode{val: 3, next: None}
= ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}} None
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the first approach is causing an issue.

Can someone explain the reason behind this and provide a solution or workaround?
Additionally, any insights into how tuple assignment works in this context would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Expanding on @Barmar: If `head.next` was `None` before this started, `head` will be assigned `None` before `head.next` is assigned to.  In your "safe" version, `head` is changed *after* `head.next` is assigned to.

Comment: See the linked question for full details (I knew I'd answered similar questions before).

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for linking ~similar~ same question.
To thing you remember question answered before 3years.

`The difference is that in your version, you assign to cur.next after you've stepped cur to cur.next, so you're actually assigning to the original cur.next.next.` This one helped me to understand the issue. Thanks again ;)

Comment: While not a duplicate, a near identical sort of problem can occur with multiple `=` assignment as well, so I'm linking the questions for bread crumbs: [Python Multiple Assignment Statements In One Line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32156515/364696)

Comment: I am finding it intimidating to ask question in stackoverflow. 2 questions asked in last 40days, 2 got -1 for each and can't even as a question for some days 

Comment: I'm sorry for your experience. My guess is the downvote is because you didn't provide a [mre], just a single function with little context.

Comment: @Barmar: I suspect there are many such duplicates scattered around the site. It's not an easy question to come up with search terms for, so I don't blame anyone who asks it again for missing the dupes (I found an even older dupe and linked both questions to it, but I'm almost certain the same question has been asked many times beyond that, and I just can't come up with search terms to find it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger It took me several tries to find the one I had answered myself. Now I've saved links to both dupes.

Comment: I see Barmar , I will try to make it more reproducible from now on.
It seems finding for duplicates is also a needed skill. Good to know @ShadowRanger
Also, question for both of you. What is this multi value assignment in one line generally called? (tuple unpacking or parallel assignment or iterable-unpacking , etc..)

Comment: @Saketh: Officially, it's called iterable unpacking (as the right-hand side can be any iterable, not just `tuple`s or `list`s or whatever; you can even do it with single-pass iterators), but it's frequently referred to, imprecisely, as tuple unpacking (in this particular case, you are, according to the Python spec, creating a `tuple` on the right-hand side and then unpacking the elements one-by-one to the left-hand targets; in practice, for fixed size cases with 1-3 elements on the right-hand side, the CPython reference interpreter uses the stack to avoid creating an actual `tuple`).